# How to not include blank fields when updating a MySQL record

Tags: php, mysql, forms, sql-update

How would I not include text fields of a form left blank in a MySQL update query? I understand why it's replacing filled fields with empty strings, but I'm not sure of an efficient way to fix it. Is the best option really just a lot of `if` statements? Is there some kind of function I could use to disallow blank fields in my html form?

Here's what I have so far:

```
//Check if record exists
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT Item_Id FROM Item_t WHERE Item_Id = '$itemid'")) == 0){
    die('The Item ID you entered was not found. Please go back and try again.');
    }

//Update record
$update = "UPDATE Item_t SET Item_Name='$itemname', Item_Price='$itemprice' WHERE Item_Id='$itemid'";
mysql_query($update);
```

So basically, in this example, if you leave the field that sets `$itemname` blank and just update `$itemprice`, the price will be updated, but the name will be set to an empty string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if your strings are empty in the SQL:

```
UPDATE Item_t
SET Item_Name = IF('$itemname' = '', Item_Name, '$itemname'),
    Item_Price = IF('$itemprice' = '', Item_Price, 'itemprice')
WHERE Item_Id='$itemid'
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense! I'm relatively new to SQL, so this is really helpful. Thanks! Quick question about what's actually going on - what's the middle expression in the IF statement mean? I understand that if the variable is an not an empty string it returns the variable, but what does returning the field name do?

Comment: @timmo: It sets the field to its original value (in other words, it doesn't change it).

Comment: You can program player

Answer (score 0):

If you're building the update string in php, you might as well just build it differently if it's empty:

```
$update = "UPDATE Item_t SET ".($itemname ? "Item_Name='$itemname', " : "")."Item_Price='$itemprice' WHERE Item_Id='$itemid'";
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this.

```
$strSet = '';


//make sure to sanitize your inputs first, then do this....
if(Item_Name != ''){ $strSet .= 'Item_Name=\'$itemname\','};
if(Item_Price != ''){ $strSet .= 'Item_Price=\'$itemprice\','};

//removes trailing comma
$strSet = substr($strSet,0,-1);

//Update record
$update = "UPDATE Item_t SET " . $strSet . " WHERE Item_Id='$itemid'";
mysql_query($update);
```

Comment: in those if statements, you don't need the curly brackets.